# accessing private variables in JAVA (AIDE)

Tags: java, android, aide-ide

```
class a{
    private int i=100;
    a(){
        //this.i=5;
    }
}
class b extends a {
    b( ){
    //super.i=10;
    a a = new a();
    System.out.println(super.i);

}

}
class c {
    public static void main(String [] args){

        b b = new b();
        }}
```

In the above program i was trying to access private variables with super keyword which i know its not possible but surprisingly in my android mobile using this AIDE (java ide)  i was able to access this with super but not directly as i have commented out in the code .i just want to know is that bug with AIDE or i am doing something wrong here.

[image]

Comment: Writing code on a touch screen would be.. fun. Sorry for the off-topic.

Comment: Note that naming variables the same thing as their class (i.e. String String, Object Object etc) is not a good habit, instead name it a aInstance or something different

Comment: @AlexColeman i was in hurry ,that's y did

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If AIDE gave you the impression you could use `super.i` in class `b` and compile it, then yes, that's a bug in AIDE. `i` has private access in `a`, and so you cannot use it outside of `a`. A Java compiler would say:

```
b.java:5: error: i has private access in a
    System.out.println(super.i);
                            ^
```

---

In Java, the **overwhelming** convention is to use an initial upper-case character in class names. You can do what you like in your own code, but when working with others or asking for help, following the conventions is probably better. So `A`, not `a`, and `B` not `b` (for the classes).

Comment: sorry for that i was hurry in typing so chose same class name as innstance variable name